# Why isn't my .gitconfig file updating on Windows after executing 'git config --global' commands?

Tags: git, git-config

.gitconfig file of windows isn't updated when after commands like git config --global xxx
and its manual updates doesn't affect git behavior.

I work on windows I have searched and there is **only one** .gitconfig file in my system it is under c:\Users\myName

When I issue global config command that actually work for example:
git config --global color.diff.old blue
This actually do change the relevant git coloring. However I don't see this update when
I can see like its updated if I do:
git config --global --list

However, I don't see the .gitconfig file in my system updated as a result.
In addition, manually updating .gitconfig doesn't change the behavior (also for definitions that don't exist in the local git config)

What is the reason for this disconnect?

Comment: Use `git config --show-origin --get color.diff.old` to find out where the setting is?

Comment: Thanks! it showed me that the relevant .gitconfig is actually on a network drive (I haven't searched). Solved